# Generate number between Gaps in the document

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I need some help on how can I check every index's value of column A
if there's a gap.

```
READ TABLE ZVBELNEXTTAB INDEX x.
curr = ZVBELNEXTTAB-EVBELN.
READ TABLE ZVBELNEXTTAB INDEX y.
next = ZVBELNEXTTAB-EVBELN.
chck = next - curr.

IF chck GT 1.

chck = chck - 1.
DO chck TIMES.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-EVBELN = curr + 1.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-BUKRS = ''.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-WERKS = ''.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-VBELN = ''.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-FKDAT = ''.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-VBLSTAT = ''.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-ZPRN = ''.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-UNAME = ''.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-TYPE = ''.
  ZVBELNEXTTAB-MANDT = ''.
  APPEND ZVBELNEXTTAB.
  SORT ZVBELNEXTTAB BY evbeln.
ENDDO.

ENDIF.
```

[image]

[image]

since SAP ABAP doesn't support the concept of using array.
I'd like to perform this action for the entire column data.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically, ABAP supports tables (arrays) since a long long time. So, what do you mean? `ABAP doesn't support the concept of using array`

Comment: in technical way of using an array i guess? unlike in other PL. i'm still a newbie in using ABAP.  I tried to make a 1 Dimensional array by setting an internal table and then i created 2nd Dimensional array with the same set of data as the 1st dimension have but by using different key field. I'm still reading and watching tutorials for future stuff that i may use.

Comment: Don't create multiple questions for the same task

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of original internal table `zvbelnexttab` And loop at copy internal table `zvbelnexttab_copy`. after that update original internal table-

```
DATA : lv_tab    TYPE sytabix.

LOOP AT zvbelnexttab_copy.

  curr = zvbelnexttab_copy-evbeln.  
  lv_tab = sy-tabix + 1.

  READ TABLE zvbelnexttab_copy INDEX lv_tab.
  next = zvbelnexttab_copy-evbeln.
  .....
  .....
  .....

ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: thanks sir. i'd tried that before :) but i guess it should be fine now thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your internal table by the field you want to fill gaps.
2. Create variable TYPE field
3. Loop at your table.
4. if itab-field <> remembered_value + 1.  <--- a gap, implement logic to insert/append whatever you want. Remember that your table is sorted and inserting there during the loop in non appropiate way may give bad results.
5. remembered_value = tab-field
6. endloop.

I suggest in point 4. you could append the new records to NEW internal table of the same type as the original and then insert it into db / merge it with your old itab.

Comment: i already generated the missing/gap between document #. but when i tried to append it in the old tab, it shows the error that there is no more space for the internal storage.

Comment: Either there is an error in your logic or I can't help you :(

Comment: i'd already fix the bugs :) i just going to add some color stuff in the ALV thanks a lot!